# Codename one-button on sidebar using theme

Tags: java, codenameone

I am trying to use the theme to put a button on sidebar, which opens options.
Which option should i use to add a button, and make a popup menu?

How it is:
[image]

How i want it to be done (button on top right, that should display popup after being clicked):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean "top left". You need to use the side menu bar see https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i-create-gorgeous-sidemenu.html

Comment: The problem is, I am using the theme in the Old gui. Code does not work. Is there a way to create this from inside the theme.res?

Comment: And I mean top right, with 3 dots/ hamburger menu. I can see it in default demo, but not add it from inside codename one.
I can go to form/command for top left, but not from top right left.

Comment: If you enable the global toolbar in your app it will work in the simulator even though it won't show in the old GUI builder.

Comment: The class Statebasemachine.java starts the form with:
  protected String getFirstFormName() {
        return "Splash";
    }

    public Container createWidget(Resources res, String resPath, boolean loadTheme) {
        initVars();
        UIBuilder.registerCustomComponent("ComponentGroup", com.codename1.ui.ComponentGroup.class);
        UIBuilder.registerCustomComponent("Form", com.codename1

etc

        return createContainer(resPath, "Splash");

Toolbar is only enabled when i put the "command" in each form, but I have 20+ forms. 
Where do i put the code for enabling global

Comment: In addition, commands are not working in the sidemenu. And hamburger sidemenu is not enabled even if I add commands. If needed, I can make a new answer with screenshots for clarification.

Comment: Edit: All i need is to add the overflow as a constant, in every form. Hamburger appears only with "command" in each form.

Comment: The Toolbar isn't available in the old GUI builder so you need to add side menu commands like I added in the video above from the code for each form. Overflow is something else it's the commands on the right side `...` button

Comment: I have tried to create the overflow menu. It appears on the default, but I was not able to make it appear yet on my Forms.
How do i make it appear, using the theme.res file? Or, where do i put the code in StateBaseMachine.java?

Comment: You never change the StateBaseMachine class. Only the StateMachine class. You need to make sure that global toolbar is active in the `init(Object)` method in your main class: `Toolbar.initGlobalToolbar(true)`.

Comment: Still not working. I just cannot make an overflow menu appear.
 Almost all examples are from the new GUI builder, which I cannot convert because I am waiting for an update that will fix its conversion issues.
Is there any example with overflow menu using the Old gui builder?

Comment: In which part  do i put such code?
https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.html


Main class:
    public void init(Object context) {
        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
              Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

State machine:
 @Override
    protected void initVars(Resources res) {
public void init(Object context) {
        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
              Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

Comment: All of the examples are for handcoding which is exactly the same as both gui builders. Overflow isn't the side menu, you need to invoke the add methods that add commands to the side menu. `init(Object)` like I said.